# Run mongoose save query in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query from my graphql resolver:

```js
  setFeatured: async function ({ id }, req) {
    const post = await Post.findById(id)
    const posts = await Post.where('_id').ne(id)
    post.featured = true
    await post.save()
    posts.forEach(pst => {
      pst.featured = false
      await post.save()
    })
    return true
  }
```

With the above code snippet I want to set status of the post that is not selected by the user to false and vice versa.

But I'm getting this error in my console

**SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function**
pointing to the line `await post.save()` inside the forEach loop.

How do I run this `save()` query for each post ?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to put async to the callback passed to forEach.

```js
posts.forEach(async pst => {
    pst.featured = false
    await post.save()
})
```

A different approach to yours, if there's a single featured post at any given time, you can separate featured field from posts and have a single record that keeps a post id.